# eventgrid event delivery failure to deliver to subscriber function

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I notice that my eventgridtopic subscription is not able to connect to subscriber function correctly and all events pushed to eventgridtopics are not being able to successfully delivering the events to subscriber function app.

I have enabled diagnostics settings of eventgrid topic and fetched the error log from the storage account which I have attached below for your review.

The main error coming while trying to push to subscriber function is:

> deliveryResponse=ResolutionError, errorCode=12007, Win32Exception: NativeErrorCode=12007, NativeErrorCode=-2147012889, Message=The server name or address could not be resolved, , httpStatusCode=InternalServerError, errorType=UnexpectedError, errorMessage=An unexpected error has occurred. Please report the x-ms-request-id header value to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket., errorMessage=The server name or address could not be resolved

What could be the issue? I am suspecting some networking issue between eventgrid to subscription function as I have tested out of corporate cloud account and the same subscription works fine.

Do you think it may be linked to eventgrid networking settings where I have public network access and it is not under vnet (and not the private endpoint access to it) but subscriber functions are private endpoints under Vnet?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when my Event Grid Topic tried to send messages to Azure function on ASE. Then I found there's impossible to deliver Event Grid through private endpoints. Please see [MS doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/consume-private-endpoints).

The best way suggested by MS is using a middleware such as Service Bus, Storage Account or Event Hubs to keep traffics inside MS networks.

I followed the same doco to set up a service bus topic and the traffic can go through.